# Does docsy have document approval feature similar to confluence? if yes, how can this be done?

Tags: document, confluence, docsy

I am migrating few documents from confluence and need to check if we have document approved process similar to confluence. I looked for official docsy website and did not find anything useful.
any pointer will be helpful.
https://www.docsy.dev/docs/ https://www.docsy.dev/docs/adding-content/ https://www.docsy.dev/docs/examples/